# extract a labelled number from a character string

Tags: r

I have a vector in a data frame which lists prices in eur, gbp and usd at the time of recording. The data lists all three values in one entry, eg:

```
X<-c( "{\"eur\": 4900, \"gbp\": 4250, \"usd\": 6120}", 
                 "{\"gbp\": 730, \"usd\": 1050}",  
                 "{\"eur\": 1050, \"gbp\": 910, \"usd\": 1310}",
                 "{\"eur\": 400, \"gbp\": 350, \"usd\": 500}" )
X
    [1] "{\"eur\": 4900, \"gbp\": 4250, \"usd\": 6120}"
    [2] "{\"gbp\": 730, \"usd\": 1050}"                
    [3] "{\"eur\": 1050, \"gbp\": 910, \"usd\": 1310}" 
    [4] "{\"eur\": 400, \"gbp\": 350, \"usd\": 500}"
```

So that one entry looks like `{"eur": 8200, "gbp": 6740, "usd": 9600}`

Most of the entries have values for eur, gbp and usd, but some have missing data for one currency, eg `{"gbp": 9700, "usd": 13650}`.

I think it might make more sense for this to be a list, or maybe 3 separate vectors, but it came out as a character when I imported the data from a csv.

What I want is to extract the GBP value from the character strings, so for `price: {"eur": 12100, "gbp": 10200, "usd": 14500}` I would get `priceGBP: 10200`.

I think I could do something overcomplicated and fudgy to get this, eg using grep to find the location of "gbp" in the string and then extract the characters following it. But I wondered if there was a neat way to do this given the structure of the data.

Could I import the csv in a different way?

Comment: plaes use `dput()` to include some reproducible data to your question

Comment: Do you give a look at regular expression ? You shloud check this cheatsheet : https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf and maybe this one https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/strings.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then you can try this -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(priceGBP=ifelse(grepl("gbp", price), 
                         gsub(".*\"gbp\": (\\d+).*", "\\1", price), 
                         NA))
```

**Output is:**

```
                                    price priceGBP
1 {"eur": 4900, "gbp": 4250, "usd": 6120}     4250
2               {"gbp": 730, "usd": 1050}      730
3               {"eur": 1050,"usd": 1310}     <NA>
4    {"eur": 400, "gbp": 350, "usd": 500}      350
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(price = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("{\"eur\": 1050,\"usd\": 1310}", 
"{\"eur\": 400, \"gbp\": 350, \"usd\": 500}", "{\"eur\": 4900, \"gbp\": 4250, \"usd\": 6120}", 
"{\"gbp\": 730, \"usd\": 1050}"), class = "factor")), .Names = "price", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great!
I'm going to do some more reading about mutate and about regular expressions now.

Comment: Great! Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `tidyverse` approach

```
library(tidyverse)
str_split(X, pattern = ",") %>% 
   map(.,~grep("gbp", ., value=T)) %>%   
   map_chr(.,~str_split(.,":", simplify = T)[2] %>% str_trim) %>% 
   as.numeric()
[1] 4250  730  910  350
```

Comment: Thanks Jimbou,

I've edited my question to include example data. My data wasn't in a list, but I've got it into a list similar to your example using stringr. But when I tried running your code, I got the indices of the gbp entries, not the gbp values: `[1] 2 2 1`. I think my problem is with map_chr?

Comment: I hope that's clear now. This is my first question on stack overflow and my formatting got a bit messed up.